# Coding a double click event in C#

Tags: c#

If I wanted to create a double click even to select a item from a listbox and message box with a option to delete the item selected how would I code this?

Comment: Can you provide some more information as to the technologies that you're using, C# with WPF, WinForms, etc?

Comment: I am currently a 1 year student in computer programming and just building a form with a array, in the form of a list box where I am needing to be able to double click and delete items from the list box and then add new items using a taxt box. Seems simple enough but for the life of me cannot figure out how to code the double click event.

Comment: @MikeOlson, I'm guessing this is a homework question as you say you're a 1st year. No problem with homework questions, just please add the homework tag. Welcome to SO and good luck on the project!

Comment: Okay thanks I will be sure to add homework tag if any further questions. So far I am at least on the right path. Just trying to figure out the coding to remove the item once ok is clicked in message box.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in `DoubleClick` event handler of your `ListBox`. (let your listbox id is **"ListBox1"**)

```
MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this.  Pretty much double click to add from one textbox to another, and double clicking from the other to remove it.  In fact, here!  Take the entire source code. Mane a new project, stick this in there, and run it.  It should be exactly what you want.  Remember, you can't just change the values on a frontside because backside will never see it, so we store the values in a hidden variable and then populate it on the back side.

ListBoxEvents.aspx
(note: ommited header)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Listbox: ORIGINAL - Controls
            var removeOriginal = false;
            var lbOriginal = 'ListBox1';
            var lbDestination = 'ListBox2'
            var lineHeight = 12;
            var lbElementsHeight = (($('[id*=' + lbOriginal + ']').find("option").length) * lineHeight) + 'px';
            //var lh = $('[id*=' + lbOriginal + ']').css('line-height');

            //Normalize Width
            $('[id*=' + lbDestination + ']').width($('[id*=' + lbOriginal + ']').width());
            $('[id*=' + lbOriginal + ']').dblclick(function () {
                //Get name and value of a selected listbox item
                var itemName = "";
                var itemValue = "";
                $('[id*=' + lbOriginal + '] option:selected').each(function () {
                    itemName += $(this).text();
                    itemValue += $(this).val();
                });
                //If user doubleclicked on empty spot, return
                if (itemName == "" && itemValue == "")
                    return;
                //Prevent duplicate appends
                var itemAlreadyExists = false
                $('[id*=' + lbDestination + '] option').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() == itemName && $(this).val() == itemValue)
                        itemAlreadyExists = true;
                });
                if (!itemAlreadyExists) {
                    $('[id*=' + lbDestination + ']').append('<option value="' + itemValue + '">' + itemName + '</option>');
                    //Select the last element in the destination listbox
                    $('[id*=' + lbDestination + '] option[selected]').removeAttr("selected");
                    $('[id*=' + lbDestination + "] option[value='" + itemValue + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
                    $('[id*=' + lbDestination + ']').animate({ scrollTop: lbElementsHeight }, 800);
                    AddItem(itemName, itemValue);
                }
                if (removeOriginal)
                    $('[id*=' + lbOriginal + "] option[value='" + itemValue + "']").remove();
            }).trigger('change');

            //Listbox: DESTINATION - Controls
            $('[id*=' + lbDestination + ']').dblclick(function () {
                //Get name and value of a selected listbox item
                var itemName = "";
                var itemValue = "";
                $('[id*=' + lbDestination + '] option:selected').each(function () {
                    itemName += $(this).text();
                    itemValue += $(this).val();
                });
                //If user doubleclicked on empty spot, return
                if (itemName == "" && itemValue == "")
                    return;
                //If we have removed the value from the original listbox, return it
                if (removeOriginal)
                    $('[id*=' + lbOriginal + ']').append('<option value="' + itemValue + '">' + itemName + '</option>');
                //Remove the value from this listbox
                $('[id*=' + lbDestination + "] option[value='" + itemValue + "']").remove();
                RemoveItem(itemName, itemValue);
            }).trigger('change');

            function AddItem(itemName, itemValue) {
                var hfLB2Items = $('[id*=hfLB2Items]');
                var item = itemName + '~' + itemValue;
                if (hfLB2Items.val() != "")
                    item = '|' + item;
                hfLB2Items.val(hfLB2Items.val() + item);
            }

            function RemoveItem(itemName, itemValue) {
                var hfLB2Items = $('[id*=hfLB2Items]');
                var item = itemName + '~' + itemValue;
                if (hfLB2Items.val().indexOf('|' + item) != -1)
                    hfLB2Items.val(hfLB2Items.val().replace('|' + item, ''));
                else if (hfLB2Items.val().indexOf(item + '|') != -1)
                    hfLB2Items.val(hfLB2Items.val().replace(item + '|', ''));
                else
                    hfLB2Items.val(hfLB2Items.val().replace(item, ''));
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="80" Height="150" style="float:left"> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="one">1</asp:ListItem> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="two">2</asp:ListItem> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="three">3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="four">4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="five">5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="six">6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="seven">7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="eight">8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="nine">9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="ten">10</asp:ListItem> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="eleven">11</asp:ListItem> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="twelve">12</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="thirteen">13</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="fourteen">14</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="fifteen">15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="sixteen">16</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="seventeen">17</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="eighteen">18</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" Width="80" Height="150" style="float:left"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbCount" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCount" runat="server" onclick="btnCount_Click" Text="ListBox 2 Item Count" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLB2Items" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <h2>Double Click Event</h2><hr />

            <p id="MyPara" style="background-color:Yellow;color:Red;font-size:2.2em;">
                Double Click here to display alert
            </p>
            <br />
            <br />

            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#MyPara").dblclick(
                        function () {
                            ShowAlert();
                        }
                    );

                });

                function ShowAlert() {
                    alert("Alert message on double click");
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ListBoxEvents.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class ListBoxEvents : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateDestinationListBox();
        int itemCount = ListBox2.Items.Count;
        tbCount.Text = itemCount.ToString();
    }
    protected void lbCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int itemCount = ListBox2.Items.Count;
        tbCount.Text = itemCount.ToString();
    }

    private void PopulateDestinationListBox()
    {
        ListBox2.Items.Clear();
        string[] pairs = hfLB2Items.Value.Split('|');
        if (pairs.Length == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pairs[0]))
            return;
        foreach (string pair in pairs)
        {
            string[] values = pair.Split('~');
            ListBox2.Items.Add(new ListItem(values[0], values[1]));
        }
    }
}
```